# Getting hours from NSDate via components

Tags: swift, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am not sure what I am missing here. I have Date object in swift, printed the description out and it is: "2000-01-01 07:00:00 +0000"

```swift
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm"
let durationDate = DateHelper.durationFormatter.date(from: “07:00”)!
let hours = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: durationDate)
```

For some odd reason the hours is coming out as 0. Not sure what I am missing here?

Comment: Normally you should be getting things in local time. You must be treating "07:00" as UTC time in your `DateHelper`.

Comment: Yea, realized that two seconds after asking the question, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I didn't take in account timezone. I am in +7 hours to UTC so it worked out perfectly to be zero.